# What is the easiest way of using setuptools and pip for handling databases

Tags: pip, setuptools, software-distribution

What would be an easy way of using pip and setuptools to distribute versionned datasets?

Would it be possible to modify the pip easily enough for it not to look in the PyPI repository but instead a different data index?

Comment: `pip install` accepts an `--index-url` option to tell it where to look for packages;  it will still try to install the package with the assumption that it is a *python* distribution;  that is, it must have a `setup.py`

Comment: Is there a way of calling this command not from a command line but by importing pip as module a into another python script?

Answer (score 1):

Using what is said in the comments you can install a dataset from a python script like this:

```
import pip

def install_dataset:
    server_url      = ....
    dataset_package = ....
    pip.main(['install','--index-url', server_url, dataset_package])
```